# seperation of variables of wave function - complex initial and boundary value condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following initial and boundary value condition of wave equation:
$$
\begin{cases}
 u_{tt}-u_{xx}=0,\\
 u\left( t,0 \right) =0,u_t\left( t,1 \right) =-1,\\
 u\left( 0,x \right) =\sin \frac{3}{2}\pi x-x,\\
 u_x\left( 1,x \right) =\sin \frac{5}{2}\pi x.\\
\end{cases}
$$

I want to use separation of variables. Let $v(t,x)=u(t,x)+x$, I can make the boundary condition homogeneous while $v$ still satisfies wave equation:

$$
\begin{cases}
 v_{tt}-v_{xx}=0,\\
 v\left( t,0 \right) =v_t\left( t,1 \right) =0,\\
 v\left( 0,x \right) =\sin \frac{3}{2}\pi x,\\
 v_x\left( 1,x \right) =\sin \frac{5}{2}\pi x+1.\\
\end{cases}
$$

Then
$$
\frac{T''}{T}=\frac{X''}{X}=-\lambda ,
$$
and $\lambda_k=(k\pi)^2$ with the boundary conditions.
so I get a series of variable-separable solutions $$
v_k=\left( A_k\sin k\pi t+B_k\cos k\pi t \right) C_k\sin k\pi x,
$$

I wonder how to proceed with the initial values and whether this method makes sense in this case... Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: How did $v_t(t,1)$ become $0$ after your substitution?

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts oops...sorry. I thought it was derivative by x...